# How to view react native application database with tables

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I'm creating a react native app. now I want to view my App database tables.
I don't know how many tables are in my SQLite database. 
I am new in react native development & SQLite please help.  to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem through the Table View command. It can also be used to view data for that table.

```js
/*Screen to view all the table*/
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { openDatabase } from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
var db = openDatabase({ name: 'UserDatabase.db' }); 
export default class ViewAllTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      FlatListItems: [],
    };
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql('SHOW TABLES', [], (tx, results) => {
        var temp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i) {
          temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        this.setState({
          FlatListItems: temp,
        });
      });
    });
  }
  ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 0.2, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#808080' }} />
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.FlatListItems}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.ListViewItemSeparator}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item, index }) => (
            <View key={item[index]} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 20 }}>
              <Text>Table: {item[index]}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```